# SIGSEGV, segmentation fault error when declaring a variable

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, segmentation-fault

I'm receiving this error I have it narrowed down to the string teamsTemp; line. What I understand from reading other posts is this normally results from not having a variable declared. In this case it is erroring out when I declare a variable. Even with the rest of the bubble sort commented out it throws an error on that variable.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    ifstream WinnersIn;     
    ifstream TeamsIn;           
    ifstream LeagueIn;        
    string inputWinner;
    string inputTeam;
    string inputLeague;
    int wins[30] = {0};
    string teams[30];
    string winner[114];
    string league[30];
    int t = 0;
    int w = 0;
    int z = 0;
    int year = 1903;
    int j;

    TeamsIn.open("Teams.txt");
    LeagueIn.open("Leagues.txt");
    WinnersIn.open("WorldSeriesWinners.txt");

    //Saving teams into an array
    while (getline(TeamsIn, inputTeam))
    {
        teams[t] = inputTeam;
        t++;
    }

    //Saving Winners into an array
        while (getline(WinnersIn, inputWinner))
    {
        winner[w] = inputWinner;
        w++;
    }

    //Saving division Winner names into an array
        while (getline(LeagueIn, inputLeague))
    {
        league[z] = inputLeague;
        z++;
    }

    //Nested for loop to match winning team and their league then output
    for (int i=0; i < 115; i++)
    {
        for (z=0; z < 30; z++)
        {
            if (winner[i] == teams[z])
            {
                cout << year << " " << winner[i] << " " << league[z] << endl;
                year++;
            }
        }
    }

    //Saving number of wins for each team into an array
    for (int i = 0; i < 115; i++)
    {
        for (z=0; z < 30; z++)
        {
            if (winner[i] == teams[z])
            {
                wins[z] = wins[z] + 1;
            }
        }
    }


    //Sorting by number of wins
    for (int i = 0; i < 29; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 30; j++)
        {
            if (wins[i] < wins[j]) 
            {
                int winsTemp;
                string teamsTemp;

                /*winsTemp = wins[i];
                wins[i] = wins[j];
                wins[j] = winsTemp;

                teamsTemp = teams[i];
                teams[i] = teams[j];
                teams[j] = teamsTemp;*/
            }
        }
    }

    TeamsIn.close();
    LeagueIn.close();
    WinnersIn.close();

    return 0;
}
```

leagues.txt
American League
National League
National League
American League
American League
National League
American League
National League
National League
American League
National League
American League
American League
National League
American League
National League
National League
American League
National League
National League
American League
No Winner
American League
American League
National League
National League
National League
National League
American League
American League

teams.txt
Anaheim Angels
Arizona Diamondbacks
Atlanta Braves
Baltimore Orioles
Boston Americans
Boston Braves
Boston Red Sox
Brooklyn Dodgers
Chicago Cubs
Chicago White Sox
Cincinnati Reds
Cleveland Indians
Detroit Tigers
Florida Marlins
Kansas City Royals
Los Angeles Dodgers
Milwaukee Braves
Minnesota Twins
New York Giants
New York Mets
New York Yankees
No Winner
Oakland Athletics
Philadelphia Athletics
Philadelphia Phillies
Pittsburgh Pirates
San Francisco Giants
St. Louis Cardinals
Toronto Blue Jays
Washington Senators

World series winners is just a list of teams that have won the world series every year.

Answer (score 2):

winner is an array of size 114 but `i` can go up to 114 which accesses element 115, which is off the end of your array.

```
        if (winner[i] == teams[z])
```

On top of that you have at least a couple places where you're reading into an array but it's not clear that you're limiting your input to the size of the array.

Comment: I have my array size declared at 114 plus 0 = an array that can hold 115 strings. The for loop says to run while i is less than 115 so it will only go to 114. Also as long as I have the bubble sort commented out it runs fine, it is something in that block of code.

Comment: @GarrettPenfield `string winner[114];` allocates an array that can hold 114 elements.  indices 0 through 113 are valid.  It does *NOT* hold 115 things.  If part of your code isn't relevant to your question then you did not post an [mcve] and should adjust your question, with an emphasis on the "minimal" part